# The layout has suddenly stopped displaying correctly in a project that uses NextJS + Sanity + Tailwind. The error: dom.js failed

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, sanity

I am build my first page with NextJS + Sanity + Tailwind.
Everything worked well, but on some page refresh layout was destroyed.
I can't understand the reason, I did not do any braking changes.
Does anybody have experience with this problem?
Network shows that dom.js failed.
I tried to delete .next and node_modules folders, but it did not help.

Thank you!

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@portabletext/react": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.17",
    "next": "13.4.17",
    "next-sanity": "^5.4.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sanity": "^3.15.1",
    "tailwind-styled-components": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.65.1"
  }
}
```

[image]